# using newer version of jquery ui alongside older version in master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

The master page on an asp.net project is using jquery 1.10.2 and jquery-ui 1.10.1.
I'm trying to use jquery 1.12.4 and jquery 1.12.1 in order to use the 'checkboxradio' feature.

I currently have this, found from http://www.ipreferjim.com/2011/06/loading-newer-versions-of-jquery-and-jquery-ui-noconflict/ but it still doesn't seem to be working right as I get

> Uncaught Error: No label found for checkboxradio widget...

In the header (also tried this after the body)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
        jQuery = $jQuery; // forces the new jQuery into global

        jQuery(function ($) {
            $.getScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js', function () {
                $("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

In the body

```
<label for="checkbox-nested-1">Heavy Metal<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-nested-1" id="checkbox1"></label>
<label for="checkbox-nested-1">Rap<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-nested-1" id="checkbox2"></label>
<label for="checkbox-nested-1">Pop<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-nested-1" id="checkbox3"></label>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try changing the 'for' attribute to use the id attribute instead of the name attribute.

Comment: that didn't seem to help. Even replaced my checkboxes with the sample from jqueryui.com and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It started working for me as soon as I changed it to use the id as mentioned in my comment.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
            var $jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
            jQuery = $jQuery; // forces the new jQuery into global

            jQuery(function ($) {
                $.getScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js', function () {
                    $("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio();
                });
            });
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <label for="checkbox1">Heavy Metal<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-nested-1" id="checkbox1"></label>
                <label for="checkbox2">Rap<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-nested-1" id="checkbox2"></label>
                <label for="checkbox3">Pop<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-nested-1" id="checkbox3"></label>
            </body>
        </html>
```